# Graph APIs to create teams channel giving 429 more often

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, rate-limiting

We are developing a bot to create team channels using Graph APIs. recently we are seeing most of the requests are getting denied with 429 or very delayed creation of rooms up to minutes in some cases.

We dont have any heavy traffic, we do create rooms 5 to 10 in a typical day. With this extreme low volume, we are getting 429 responses. We have also inbuilt mechanism to retry. However the API functionality is unpredictable and causing inconsistent experience for our application.

Any thoughts or pointers in what to look for or avoid will be helpful.

Thanks
Laksh

Comment: I don't see any issue with api's. Once check your bot logic, if it is sending multiple requests. Check your logic as well if that is causing this issue.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT we have thoroughly investigated our bot logic and its not sending more than a request within a sec, and also totally about 40 API calls we make in a day.  Our question is to find out if there is a way to create certain type of accounts to get guaranteed response. Any pointers will help us move forward.

Comment: All the types of account should receive same response. This doesn't look like any account type issue. API call limit is very high, 40 calls in a day will not throw 429. Did this api worked for you anytime since app is developed?

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT the APIs were working well until around Apr 22nd when we started noticing frequent 429. There is no change in our API from our side, thats why trying to understand if anything changed on MS Teams side.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT any update you can provide on this issue?

Comment: Missed to respond you. There is no change happened that can cause this issue.